# When to use "myself" or "me"

Tags: grammaticality, personal-pronouns, reflexives

Which is grammatically correct?

> - "Request you to register me for the course"
> - "Request you to register myself for the course"

Answer (score 4):

> I request you to register **me/myself** on the course.

Here, *me* or *myself* is the object of the verb *register.* To determine which to use, it's necessary to consider who is the agent of that verb: who is actually doing the registering.

If *“I”* is the person doing the registering, then *“I”* is also the object of the verb *register* and *myself* is appropriate. It's called a ***reflexive*** pronoun, because the action is reflected back on to the person doing it.

If *“you”* is the person doing the registering, having *“I”* as the object (which is different) means that *myself* is not appropriate and *me* should be used.

> I request you to register me on the course.

In the above example, *you* do the registering, so you register *me*. However, in the next sentence, *I* do the registering, so I register *myself*.

> I have to register myself on the course.

Having *I* as the subject of *request* does not affect which word to use as the object of *register*. For example, if *“he”* is to do the registering:

> I requested him to register me on the course.
>   I requested him to register himself on the course.

Comment: Nice, but I'm pretty sure it's a duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I did look, but I couldn't find one where the pronoun is the object of a verb like this. That doesn't mean that such a question doesn't exist, of course.

Comment: It's maybe worth mentioning that "myself" is sometimes used for contrast or emphasis. So you may find e.g. "Please register myself but not Jim" being used by some speakers.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that that use is **completely** wrong.

Comment: Ah. So the people should be shot.

Comment: The use of Xself as an object is mentioned in the 'When to use “me” or “myself”?' thread.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Your answer is a bit misleading. Reflexive pronouns are not necessarily direct objects.

Comment: @Araucaria You are generalising from the particular.

Comment: Not really: *It's called a reflexive pronoun, because the action is reflected back on to the person doing it*. This isn't true: *He was beside himself*

Comment: Yes. In respect of this question, how I answered it is not wrong.

Comment: It's a good answer, which I have upvoted :) I just think that particular sentence might be a bit misleading? It is of course your answer - which you must answer yourself! :)

Comment: I'm going to edit the question in a bit. I think that as you said this is really a very different situation from the one in the linked question. There is no *overt* subject of the verb here.