# "I knew this would interest you as much as it did me"

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, syntactic-analysis, personal-pronouns, reflexives

Is this the correct way to write this sentence? I thought about saying, "I knew this would interest you as much as it did myself", but wasn't sure if 'me' or 'myself' would be correct.

Comment: The reflexive "myself" would be wrong -- "me" is fine

Comment: Related: [When is it correct to use “yourself” and “myself” (versus “you” and “me”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1176) I don't think the answers are very helpful, though.

Comment: Here is another related question, with an answer that I am not sure about because it doesn't cite anything: [Should I use “me” or “myself” here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160554) Maybe [When to use “myself” or “me”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188787) is more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries provide answers to this type of question.

According to Dictionary.com, Art. "myself",
the pronoun "myself"
1. gives more intensity to "me"
2. and is used

> in place of I or me after ***as***, *than*, or *but* [my bold]

The second aspect suggests that while "me" is not wrong, "myself" seems to be more common.

I don't know though if there is a reason why "myself" is preferred over "me".

Comment: _I don't know though if there is a reason why "myself" is preferred over "me"._ Just pretentiousness in my opinion.

Comment: You’re misreading the dictionary. Or rather, misparsing the sentence. “After _as_, _than_, or _but_” doesn’t mean “at any place in a clause that has one of these three words somewhere before it”, but “as the object of these three prepositions”. _Me/myself_ is not the object of _as_ here; the quoted part is not relevant. _Me_ would definitely be a lot more common than _myself_ in this case.